# Modal Textarea reloads with every click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

Ihave this modal with 2 textarea, but every time that i type some keybord it just stop and go out of the text area.

the problem is on **onChange={event => setTitle(event.target.value)}** but i dont know what can i do.

```
      <Modal.Body>
            <form onSubmit={Patch} className="form">
                <div className="control">
                    <div className="field">
                        <h2>What's in your mind?</h2>
                        <textarea
                            className="input1"
                            type="text"
                            value={title}
                            placeholder="enter your title"
                            onChange={event => setTitle(event.target.value)}
                        />
                    <

                    /div>
                <div className="field">
                    <textarea
                        className="input2"
                        type="text"
                        value={content}
                        placeholder="insert your content"
                        onChange={event => setContent(event.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-btn">
                    <button onClick={() => setModalshow2(false)} disabled={!title || !content} type="submit" className="btnSend">CREATE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </Modal.Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type something in the text area, the parent component is also re-rendering. Try with autoFocus attribute

```
<textarea
    className="input2"
    type="text"
    value={content}
    placeholder="insert your content"
    onChange={event => setContent(event.target.value)}
    autoFocus
/>
```